# Чтение вещественных чисел из файла delphi

Tags: delphi

Каким образом осуществить? При попытке чтения с помощью функции read выдает ошибку "invalid numeric input".

Пример файла:

```
1254,1 1345,88 24,24
```

Пример кода:

```
procedure example();
var f: TextFile ;
    i: integer;
    j:double;
begin
AssignFile(f, 'text.txt');
Reset(f);
for i := 1 to 3 do
read(f,j);
end;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос код чтения и пример формата файла.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо запятой использовать точку, если поможет то меняйте локаль в программе.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код противоречит сам себе.

Вы используете **текстовый** файл, а пытаетесь читать из него число.
Читайте строку и преобразовывайте ее в число через `StrToFloat`, например:

```
var
  FS: TFormatSettings;
  s: string;

GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, FS);
FS.DecimalSeparator:=',';
read(f, s);
j := StrToFloatDef(s, 0, FS);
```

P.S. Крайне желательно уйти от использования функций `AssignFile`/`Append`/`Read`/`Write` в пользу более правильных классов `TStringList`, `TStringStream`, etc...

Comment: По Вашему коду в s записывается вся строка (до символа конца строки, а не пробела, я имею в виду), а j=0, мне же нужно считать все числа последовательно

Comment: @Dec. В тексте моего ответа ошибка (чего-то многовато на сегодня) - код не противоречит (забыл, как работает read/readln), но для правильной работы в файле разделитель целой и дробной части должен быть `.`. Прямая установка DecimalSeparator эффекта не дает. Если изменить исходный формат файла нет возможности - нужно разделять данные самому, используя в качестве разделителя пробел.